# Logical comparison operators without control statements

Tags: c

Consider this:

```
    main()
    {
      int i = 1;
      fork(); fork(); fork();
      printf("%d ",i);
    }
```

The output of the above code is:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

That is, at the end there are 8 (2^3) processes reaching the `printf()` line. Now consider the code below:

```
    main()
    {
      int i = 1;
      fork() && fork() || fork();
      printf("%d ",i);
    }
```

Initially, I thought there'd be no change in the output because the results of the comparisons using `&&` , `||` are not being evaluated by a control statement like `if` or `while`. That is, they're being discarded. However, The output of this code is:

```
1 1 1 1 1
```

Meaning, at the end there are 5 processes that reach the `printf()` line.

**My question: What does this line do**

```
 fork() && fork()||fork();
```

Definitely, something  has changed. I've never contemplated using comparison operators like `&&` , `||` without control statements like `if`, `while` to evaluate the result of the comparison and accordingly take some action. I thought, without these control constructs, the comparison operators are meaningless; they'd simply return `1` or `0` without anything being done about it.

Clearly, I'm mistaken, and am totally unaware of this usage of the  operators.

Comment: Perhaps writing code that is sensible would be a good start

Comment: @EdHeal This was a puzzle.

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate. The question is not about fork(). As it turns out , it is about something called, "short circuiting of operators". A person who has never heard of this term before cannot look this up (which is the case, this time)

Comment: @sanjeevmk - the titles might be different, but it is a duplicate because the core of the question (using logical `&&` and `||` operators on a `fork()` call) and the answers (how to evaluate this statement) are the same as yours.

Comment: I've revised the title of the duplicate question so that it better reflects what is inside (and specifically mentions && and || in the title).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fork()` returns the PID for a child process if it’s returning in the parent, or `0` if it’s returning in the child. Logical operators short-circuit in C, so `a && b` doesn’t evaluate `b` if `a` is `0`, and `a || b` doesn’t evaluate `b` if `a` is not `0`.

So you fork once. Two processes. The right side of the `&&` only gets evaluated in the child. Three processes. The right side of the `||` gets evaluated in the same child again. Four processes. But wait! `&&` binds tighter than `||`, so the parent process also forks again, for a total of five processes.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it's not part of a conditional check, the following statement:

```
exp1 && exp2 || exp3;
```

Would still evaluate per boolean expression evaluation rules. In this case, if `exp1` is false (0), then `exp2` will be skipped since `exp1 && exp2` is already determined to be false. And if `exp1 && exp2` is true (not 0), then `exp3` will be skipped since the whole expression is then determined to already be true.